# Javascript Regular Expression (exp)? issues

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written a Javascript regular expression as below

```
/^(\[)(\d{1,2}([-]\d{1,2})?[,])*(\])$/
```

I am trying to validate against input text [21] but it fails. I am verifying using http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/javascript/index.html

I am suspecting an issue with `([-]\d{1,2})?`

Inputs that should pass are [12-23] or [34] or [12-23,34]
Please help

Comment: It's because the comma isn't optional. As an aside, no need to put `-` and `,` in a character class.

Comment: Even /^(\[)(\d{1,2}([-]\d{1,2})?[,]?)*(\])$/ doesn't seem to work. Can you please with the correct regex .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression includes the part `[,]` which translates as "must contain a comma in that position".

If the comma is indeed required then `[21]` will not evaluate but `[21,]` will.

If the comma should have been optional that part of the expression should have been `[,]?` which makes in zero or one repetition, or perhaps `[,]*` which is any number of repetitions.

Final working expression was `^(\[)(\d{1,2}([-]\d{1,2})?[,]?)*(\])$` which passes on all of your expected inputs.

*Enhancement* - As noted in comments, your wrapping a single character in square braces, indicating a class of characters. This is not necessary when your class of characters has just one character, and makes a hard-to-read syntax like regexp even harder. Your expression can be shortened to `^(\[)(\d{1,2}(-\d{1,2})?,?)*(\])$`

Comment: /^(\[)(\d{1,2}([-]\d{1,2})?[,]?)*(\])$/ doesn't pass [21]

Comment: The square brackets need to be escaped, as they were in your original question, and my answer! Why did you change it?

Comment: @Jamiec: I think they are, but without markdown you can't see them.

Comment: @VinodJayachandran - works for me, using the regex checker you linked: http://fiddle.re/1ht8c6

Comment: This will match a trailing comma, for example `[1,2,]` passes.  But, maybe that is acceptable